# sql job to stop duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a sql job running which is importing from an old database to a new database. however, i would like  to setup a schedule for the job to run every hour and not import duplicates.

job running:

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName
SELECT [Column1]
      ,[Column2]
      ,[Column3]
      ,[Column4]
      ,GETDATE() AS [Column5]
FROM OldTableName
```

if i assign a primary key to [Column2], the job fails with the following error:

Message

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'NewTableName'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.NewTableName'. The duplicate key value is (0001). [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 2627)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type is the PRIMARY KEY column, and is it an IDENTITY ?

Comment: I have manage to resolve the issue myself

by adding:
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(
Select [Column2] FROM NewTableName
WHERE NewTableName.[KeyId] = OldTableName.[KeyId]  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by adding:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( Select [Column2] 
FROM NewTableName 
WHERE NewTableName.[KeyId] = OldTableName.[KeyId] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT )
```